# What is responsible for font rendering on linux?

Tags: linux, fonts, window-managers

I am sorry if my question is a bit vague.  I am trying to understand where to look for my problems.  I have a regression test suite that captures and compare the screen.  It seems like whenever we do some kind of library upgrade the regression tests would fail.   Our font settings are the same.   The difference would be like the graphics card upgrade (driver), window manager upgrade, or just third party library upgrade (for example Qt library).  From human visual testing, the fonts look almost identical, but if I do pixel to pixel comparison, it would show that the snapshots are different.  Does anyone have insight how the fonts are rendered ?

Comment: If you find a good solution, please notify browser makers everywhere so they can fix the [canvas fingerprinting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canvas_fingerprinting) issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Graphics rendering on Linux is a proper mess. While Linux is about as old as Windows, Linux first tried to copy the old X11 window system. This was one of the oldest GUI systems in the world, and it shows - the API is beyond horrible. As a result, lots and lots of libraries were stacked on top of X11 to make it workable, with various degrees of compatibility.

To make things worse, X11 was not just a single implementation, there were competing X11 implementations. Linux chiefly used XFree86, which later became Xorg. And because that's not confusing enough, recent developments added a number of alternatives to X11, which support backwards-compatibility interfaces to X11. Some of those GUI libraries on top of X11 are aware of these new libraries, and may now use the new interfaces.

So, you basically have a pretty fragile system, and any library with a decent programming model has shaky foundations. It's no wonder that changing any part may suddenly cause re-rendering, possibly even choosing entirely new rendering paths.

Windows is a bit better, but it too is old and has some competing GUI libraries. The reason why it's better is probably threefold: there's a single party in control of all the interfaces (Microsoft), they were aware of the bad X11 design from the start (avoided beginner mistakes) and Microsoft has far more resources to spend.

But still, both Linux and Windows had to evolve to support Unicode and the much larger fonts it brought, 24 bits color, high-DPI screens, LCD screens with subpixel resolution, accelerated GPU's, etc. And it's been hard for both to dump old interfaces.